# How do you add multiple statements to an IF Function?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to add multiple statements to a formula so that it looks like this:

**Note Column A begins at 2015 and descends**

- `If B1 = 2015 (A1), then C1 = 5`
- `If B1 is between 2013 (A3) and 2014 (A2), then C1 = 4 (Less than 2015?)`
- `If B1 is between 2010 (A6) and 2012 (A4), then C1 = 3 (Less than 2013?)`
- `If B1 is between 2006 (A10) and 2009 (A7), then C1 = 2 (Less than 2010?)`
- `If B1 < than 2006 (A10), then C1 = 1`

[image]

It cuts off at 2008 but pretend it goes down to at least 2006, which would be cell A10. The function goes in Column C so that cells in Column B meet the above criteria that I listed. Here C1 should have a 2 because it is in between 2006 and 2008 (cells A10 and A8), C2 should have a 3 because it is in between 2010 and 2012 (cells A6 and A4)...etc.

I do not know how to go about it however. I came up with this formula below, but it doesn't seem to work:

`IF(B1=$A$1,5,IF(B1<$A$1,4,IF(B1<$A$3,3,IF(B1<$A$6,2,IF(B1<$A$10,1,0)))))`

Would a VLOOKUP function work better here? And if so please share

This may seem redundant considering the years are next to each other, but I am using this in another spreadsheet to score the years 1 through 5, this is just an example.

Thank you.

Comment: not sure if this will work but  `IF B1="2015"` .....

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. Please show us an example of the desired result so we can suggest a good way forward.

Comment: It cuts off at 2008 but pretend it goes down to at least 2006. The function goes in Column C to find out if a cell in column B meets the above criteria that I listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting IFs is OK, you almost got it right. What you're doing wrong is your conditional expressions.

- If `B1 is 2015`, then `C1 = 5`. That should work.
- If `B1 is 2014`, then `C1 = 4`. That works, too.
- But what happens if `B1 is 2011`? 2011 is less than 2015 too... so your formula will make `C1 = 4` instead of 3.

You can rewrite it like this:

```
=IF(B1=2015, 5,
    IF(B1>=2013, 4,
       IF(B1>=2010, 3,
          IF(B1>=2006, 2, 1)
       )
    )
 )
```

Or without the extra spaces:

```
=IF(B1=2015,5,IF(B1>=2013,4,IF(B1>=2010,3,IF(B1>=2006,2,1))))
```

Another option would be to use a "translation table", and then use `VLOOKUP` instead. You would have the following columns:

```
D     E
----  ----
2015  5
2014  4
2013  4
2012  3
2011  3
...   ...
```

Your formula would be then something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, D:E, 2, FALSE)
```

The parameters passed to VLOOKUP mean:

- What are you looking for: the value in B1.
- Where you will look it: your 2 new columns, D and E.
- What column will the result be returned from: the second one, E.
- FALSE because the data is not ordered ascending, and we want to find an exact match.

Comment: GREAT THANKS for both options, VERY HELPFUL :D

Answer (score 1):

A little bit too late but shorter :-)

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$10,0),5,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,1)
```